# Display images from xml file in Shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I have a shell script that grabs the weather and then displays it on my raspberry pi, but I want to add images based on the temperature. I have images just not sure how to add it to the shell script. It's using `sed` to grab data off the xml file. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Feeting Cambridge weather..
wget -O yw.htm http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12779904\&u=f -o log.txt
echo Processing..
grep -A4 -i 'Current' yw.htm > yw
sed '1d' yw > yw2
sed '2d' yw2 > yw
sed -i 's/<br \/>//g' yw
sed -i 's/<BR \/>//g' yw
sed -i 's/High/\nHigh/g' yw
echo `date` >> yw
echo Displaying..
sudo ./weather.py
echo Done
```

So let me sum up what I would like one more time: I want to display an image based on the temperature from a xml file. Also is this even possible? I'm new to shell script so be easy.

UPDATE: Based on some of the comments: I want the image on the right and weather.py opens the html page in netsurf on the raspberry pi

```
os.system('netsurf file///home/pi/yw')
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What data do you want to extract from the `html` page? Where are the images and how are related with the temperatures? What does the `python` script do?

Comment: where do you want this image to show up?

Comment: I have image created in photoshop or even better if you launch the url in the code it shows some images with it can i display those images?

Comment: You would be better off doing most of this in your python file, including generating an image name based on a range of numbers...

Comment: I have no idea how though I'm no good a prasing xml files